# Performance improvement on SQL query joining table on itself

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

I'm running this query on a table with approximately 20MM records in it.  It's a very slow query, and I'm wondering if there's a better way to accomplish this that might run faster ?

```
delete previous
output Deleted.*
into table_A
from table_B as previous
inner join table_B as latest on previous.field_1 = latest.field_1
    and previous.field_2 = latest.field_2
    and previous.field_3 = latest.field_3
where previous.[feed_id] < latest.[feed_id]
    and previous.[condition_1] in (
        '1'
        ,'2'
        )
    and latest.[condition_1] = '3'
    and latest.[feed_id] = 500
```

Comment: How many rows does this query identify and you are trying to delete? If it's a small number, you may want to just select those rows into a temporary structure, and then delete those identified rows based on a join (and perhaps in chunks). If it's most of the table and you're only keeping a small %, consider dumping just the keepers into a second table, dropping/renaming the original, and renaming the new. Also try to work out the LAG syntax required to identify the rows you want - this should be more efficient than a self-join (though I doubt that's your actual problem - rather the logging).

Comment: There are going to be upwards of 10MM records that will be deleted on this particular run.  Can you explain what you mean by "LAG Syntax"?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing the entire delete in one transaction that will possibly bloat your transaction log and it will crawl like a sloth.

There is a [much better way of doing a delete - break it into chunks](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes) or you can do deletes using [Careful Batching](http://michaeljswart.com/2014/09/take-care-when-scripting-batches/).

Also, its [always a good habit to refer objects with their schema](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix).

Comment: ok, so you're essentially suggesting I use dynamic SQL to delete in "batches"?  I do specify the schema in my code, but I simplified it a bit for SO.

Comment: @Jon Why would you need dynamic SQL? Did you read the links?

Comment: My bad, my use of the term was incorrect...after a quick initial scan of the "careful batching" link, I saw the author was using a while loop and setting variables for use in the script and I incorrectly called that dynamic sql.  Better to show off my inexperience here and learn, than do it in a job interview, amiright?  ;)